# Requiring images in React Native with latest gradle fails release builds

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, aapt

If I update to the latest Gradle and then require an image in React Native, I cannot build release builds.

I posted [an issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16906) on React Native, but maybe you guys have more ideas :)

I created a small [test project](https://github.com/Almouro/react-native-with-gradle-4) but here are the steps to reproduce it:

1. Init a new project: `react-native init Test`
2. Update to latest Gradle:

   - Open Android Studio and install recommended version
   - Build from Android Studio, it should ask you to update build tools, do so
3. Require an image in `index.js`
4. Run `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

#### Expected Behavior

The command `./gradlew assembleRelease` should not fail

#### Actual Behavior

Running `./gradlew assembleRelease` when the image is required from the JS fails with:

`/Users/almouro/bam/uefa/TestGradle3/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/drawable-mdpi/image.png: error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file..
error: failed parsing overlays.`

If the image is not required, the command works fine.

#### Reproducible Demo

```
git clone https://github.com/Almouro/react-native-with-gradle-4
yarn
cd android
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

#### Workaround

Adding `android.enableAapt2=false` to `android/gradle.properties` fixes the issue but it is only a workaround, and Instant app capabilities will not work.

Do you guys have any idea?

My understanding is that the React Native bundleJS gradle task copies all the images in the android merged resources folder, but aapt now expects images there to be compiled in `.flat` files.

Comment: Which version of the gradle plugin are you using? This is an error you'd get if you had 'new resource processing' turned off, but 'enable aapt2' enabled. Both are enabled by default in the 3.0 plugin, and aapt2 should not be used in 2.x version, as it was highly unstable at that point.

Comment: Hi @IzabelaOrlowska, I'm using [gradle plugin version 3.0.0](https://github.com/Almouro/react-native-with-gradle-4/blob/master/android/build.gradle) with Gradle with [Gradle 4.3.1](https://github.com/Almouro/react-native-with-gradle-4/blob/master/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties#L5)

Comment: oh I didn't notice the reproducible demo you added, I'll take a look and see what the issue is

Comment: Hi, @Almouro any progress on this issue that isn't the workaround? Thanks

Comment: Hi @UriKlar, a fix on React Nativewas made, then reverted. The issue (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16906) is still open, unfortunately. I had no luck myself figuring how to use aapt v2.